# Rewriting $\sum_{{i,j=0}\:\:i\ne j}^n \binom{n}{i}\:\:\binom{n}{j}$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation, contest-math, combinations

> Solve $$\sum_{{i,j=0}\:\:i\ne j}^n \binom{n}{i}\:\:\binom{n}{j}$$ This was a contest math problem which I was not able to solve.

My work: I was very unsure about how to approach this question. In my opinion, there will be many combinations and I tried listing them but wasn't able to find a general pattetn.

The options given were:

> $2^{2n}-\binom{2n}{n}$

> $2^{2n-1}-\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$

> $2^{2n}-\frac12\binom{2n}{n}$

> $2^{n-1}-\binom{2n-1}{n}$

The answer given by me was $2^{2n}-\binom{2n}{n}$
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\sum_{{i,j=0};\:i\ne j}^n \binom{n}{i}\:\:\binom{n}{j}=
$$
$$
\sum_{{i,j=0}}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}-
\sum_{{i,j=0};\:i=j}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\stackrel{\ast}{=}
$$
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\cdot
\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}-
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{i}
$$

In step $\ast$ "disentangle" the double sum of a product where the factors depend only on one of the summation variables using distributivity several times (marked by $\ast\ast$):

$$
\sum_{{i,j=0}}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}=
$$
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n \left(\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\right)\right)\stackrel{\ast\ast}{=}
$$
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n \left(\left(\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\right)\binom{n}{j}\right)\stackrel{\ast\ast}{=}
$$
$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}\right)=
$$
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\cdot
\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}
$$

Then use some [standard identities on sums of binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Sums_of_the_binomial_coefficients) in step $\ast\!\ast\!\ast$ to get:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\cdot
\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}-
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{i}=
$$
$$
\left(\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\right)^2-
\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\binom{n}{i}^2\right)\stackrel{\ast\ast\ast}{=}
$$
$$
\left(2^n\right)^2-
\binom{2n}{n}=
2^{2n}-
\binom{2n}{n}
$$

Comment: How have you distributed sigma over multiplication $?$

Comment: I "disentangled" a double sum of a product where the factors depend only on one of the summation variables - distributivity occured: $\sum_{{i,j=0}}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}=\sum_{j=0}^n\left(\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\right)\binom{n}{j}=\left(\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\right)\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}=
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}\cdot
\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}$

Comment: Understood ....thanks

Answer (score 0):

Examine the function $f(x)$

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n{n \choose i}{n \choose j}x^ix^j$$

where the summation we want is given by

$$S = f(1) - \sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}^2$$

Computing each iterated sum, we get

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}x^i(1+x)^n = (1+x)^{2n}$$

and

$$\sum_{i=0}^n{n \choose i}^2 = {2n \choose n}$$

by the Vandermonde identity, or combinatorial argument. This means what we are after is

$$S = 2^{2n} - {2n \choose n}$$